# Is there a tool that computes what happens in a method based on the values of the args passed in?

Tags: debugging, testing, code-coverage, desk-check

I'm working on a legacy app that is not just spaghetti, but turns to egg shells when broken (Humpty Dumpty syndrome), where figuring out what is going on as the code meanders around like a drunken sailor in Old Manila is like trying to find a poodle in a smokestack.

As an example, here is a method that I must grok; this is just the first part of it:

```
private void InitializeBackgroundThread( LoginStatuses loginStatus, string DialogCap )
{
    try
    {
        double pause         = 1;
        int    wait          = 250;
        ProgressChangedFlag  = false;
        ProgressChangedIndex = 0;
        pc                   = new PendingCommands( pause, wait );

        PendingCommands.ProcessCommands = true;

        if (!((loginStatus == LoginStatuses.LoginVendors) || (loginStatus == LoginStatuses.LoginInventory)))
            PendingCommands.Processing = false;

        PendingCommands.Timeout        = false;
        Util.StopCancelRequested       = false;

        if( timeOut != "" )
            pc.timeOut = timeOut;

        if (!((loginStatus == LoginStatuses.LoginVendors) || (loginStatus == LoginStatuses.LoginInventory)))
        {
            InitializeBackgroundThread_CCRLoginTerminate        (true);
            InitializeBackgroundThread_CCRTimerExceeded         (true);
            InitializeBackgroundThread_CCROnline                (true);
        }

        if (loginStatus == LoginStatuses.LoginVendors)
        {
            InitializeBackgroundThread_CCRCommandConfirmedGetsites  (false);
            InitializeBackgroundThread_CCRCommandConfirmed      (false);
            InitializeBackgroundThread_CCRCommandConfirmedSitesetup (true);
        }
        else if (loginStatus == LoginStatuses.LoginSitesData)
        {
            InitializeBackgroundThread_CCRCommandConfirmed      (false);
            InitializeBackgroundThread_CCRCommandConfirmedSitesetup (false);
            InitializeBackgroundThread_CCRCommandConfirmedGetsites  (true);
        }
        else
        {
            InitializeBackgroundThread_CCRCommandConfirmedSitesetup (false);
            InitializeBackgroundThread_CCRCommandConfirmedGetsites  (false);
            InitializeBackgroundThread_CCRCommandConfirmed      (true);
        }

        InitializeBackgroundThread_CCRProgress              (true);
        InitializeBackgroundThread_CCRProgressChanged       (true);
        InitializeBackgroundThread_CCRProgressComm          (true);
```

Now I can "deskcheck" it by going through it with a notepad, asking myself, "Okay, what will happen - which variables will be assigned which values, and which methods will be called - if loginStatus is "AllQuiet"? What if loginStatus is "SNAFU"? Etc. etc. ad nauseum.

Wouldn't it be great if a tool could eat this spaghetti right up and spit out a report such as:

```
*With a loginStatus of "AllQuiet"
PendingCommands.Processing is set to true.
InitializeBackgroundThread_CCRProgressChanged is called.
...
With a loginStatus of "SNAFU"
(etc.)*
```

This would be a "killer" debugging/sanity check tool. I know there are code coverage tools, but are there any that are this sophisticated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't code coverage, which simply tracks what code gets executed if you run a specific test.

What you want is something like a cross between program slicing ("show me everything downstream/upstream from some code point" aka  'a slice' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_slicing),
and partial evaluation ("show me what this code looks like if I assume some value is a specific constant" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation).  And you want it to display the result superimposed on top of your actual code (e.g. boldface the selected part) to see your focus.

Yes, that would be wickedly nice tool.

No, I don't know of any.   There are program slicers for C and C++ (See http://www.grammatech.com/research/technologies/codesurfer).  I don't think they have the partial evaluation part, but I think they do have some other options to minimize the size the slice being inspected.